# Custom Homepage Pagination using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have a situation and all the searching I've done hasn't led me to a successful outcome. I have a static homepage template with a custom wp_query that looks like the following (which works on another site on a custom page--Also, I have posts_per_page set to 1 for testing purposes and I have posts set to 1 in the dashboard):

```
<?php 
    global $paged;
    global $bday_parties;
    $temp = $bday_parties; 
    $bday_parties = null; 

    $bday_parties = new WP_Query(); 
    $bday_parties->query('category_name=party-themes&posts_per_page=1&post_type=page'.'&paged='.$paged);
    while ($bday_parties->have_posts()) : $bday_parties->the_post(); 
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="article-border">
        <?php get_template_part('partials/loop-homeparties'); ?>
    </div>      
</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $bday_parties ) ); ?>
</div>
<?php 
    $bday_parties = null; 
    $bday_parties = $temp; 
?>
```

The partials/loop-homeparties template is pulling meta values from custom meta boxes on a page and that content is making up the "posts" on the homepage (as well as on archive pages).

Using the above query, I get the content on the home page, I get the nav links but when I click (the link shows the URL for the next page) the home page just reloads. I've been working on this for a couple of days now and the site needs to launch soon (this is holding me up). Since it works on another page successfully, I don't understand why it isn't working for me here. Any help would be appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 1):

> Since it works on another page successfully, I don't understand why it isn't working for me here.

The problem is other page is not *Static Front Page*. When paging a static page, WordPress use the `page` variable, not the `paged` query variable. Pages use `<!--nextpage-->` to paginate. From the [WP_Query page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters):

> Pagination Note: Use get_query_var('page'); if you want your query to work in a Page template that you've set as your static front page. The query variable 'page' also holds the pagenumber for a single paginated Post or Page that includes the `<!--nextpage-->` Quicktag in the post content.
>
> Display posts from current page on a static front page:
>
> `$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;`
> `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );`

In your code, this:

```
global $paged;
global $bday_parties;
$temp = $bday_parties;
$bday_parties = null;

$bday_parties = new WP_Query();
$bday_parties->query('category_name=party-themes&posts_per_page=1&post_type=page'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($bday_parties->have_posts()) : $bday_parties->the_post();
```

Could be rewritten as this:

```
global $bday_parties;

$temp = $bday_parties;
$bday_parties = null;

$bday_parties = new WP_Query();

$page_number = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$bday_parties->query( 'category_name=party-themes&posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&page=' . $page_number );
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I just tried your code and it didn't work. I've basically tried every bit of code I've come across and I can't get anything to work. I'd be happy to settle for "Next/Prev" links at this point.

Comment: @JusticeIsCheap "didn't work" is no proper error or problem description.

Comment: When I say "didn't work" I'm getting the exact same results as my code I posted. It's still reloading the same page.

Comment: What url did you use to find for page 2? If you are using the link from the `wp_pagenavi` function. What url is it producing?

Comment: I don't know if you can access this site or not, but here's the [site](http://174.129.234.210/parents/birthday-parties/) I'm working on and the URL wp_pagenavi is giving me is [this](http://174.129.234.210/parents/birthday-parties/page/2/)

Comment: Yes. I can see those links. Let me set this up on a test server and see if I can spot the problem.

Comment: Did you really name your category `party-themes`? All lowercase? If this is the slug, use `category=party-themes` in the query.

Comment: I changed the category as you suggested and I still reload the homepage when trying to page. The only difference is I got 9 pages for pagingation, opposed to the 2 I should have. I played around a bit and changed the theme from having a static page to "Your Latest Posts" and the pagination works almost perfectly. The only problem I'm having with that is I can't sort the posts in any specific order. I've tried orderby ID, date and I still seem to get them in the order originally posted (oldest first).

Comment: You should ask a new question for that. The comments is not a good place to answer new questions. I'm glad you stopped using a static front page. The WP programmers [never intended](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) for that option to be paged. None of the next / previous link functions do not work on static front pages.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, appreciate it and if ceaseless amounts of searching elsewhere doesn't answer my sorting problem, I'll be back here to ask. 

Thanks again!